# Magento 2 - Write plugin for API interface

Tags: magento2, api, plugin, webapi, after-plugin

In the documentation it says:

> *"A plugin, or interceptor, is a class that modifies the behavior of public class functions by intercepting a function call and running
> code before, after, or around that function call. This allows you to
> substitute or extend the behavior of original, public methods **for
> any class or interface**."*

But is this also true for API?

I try to write a **afterSave** Plugin for the class **Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface** to log something if the quote is getting saved.

But it does not work and no log is created.

**app/code/Company/Checkout/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="Company_Checkout_CartItemRepositoryInterface" type="Company\Checkout\Plugin\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/Checkout/Plugin/Quote/Api/CartItemRepositoryInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Checkout\Plugin\Quote\Api;

class CartItemRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $_cartFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cartFactory
    ) {
        $this->_cartFactory = $cartFactory;
    }

    public function afterSave(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem)
    {
        $cart = $this->_cartFactory->create();
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();

        \Eddcapone\ChromePhp\Helper\ChromePhp::log("Hello from afterSave Plugin (API: module-quote/api/CartItemRepositoryInterface/save");
        \Eddcapone\ChromePhp\Helper\ChromePhp::log("QuoteId = ". $quote->getId());
    }



}
```

**Update:**

The reason was, that I tried to log by using chromePhp, which does not seem to work at API Interface plugins... Now I used this approach to log it:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/zend_debug.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info("afterSave test");
```

...and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder in which your di file is placed is key. In your example the plugin only get executed for the frontend area.

I recommend putting it without frontend so it is used everywhere. If this is not wanted use the needed API area: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html

Comment: I put it in MODULE/etc now, but it does still not work.

Comment: I recommend setting up xdebug and set a breakpoint to make sure it is the problem and not the way you log it

Comment: The way I log it works 100%. It also works in other plugins. I think it is just impossible to define plugins for API Interfaces.

Comment: You were right, my log method does not work in API Interface plugins, I think because they are not communicating with the browser... I logged to a file instead and now it showed the message :) so the plugin was triggered.